# Upsert query with only one record to insert/update

Tags: apex, soql, upsert

Is it possible to upsert only a single object? And return the ID of the inserted/updated record?

I have an Custom Contact Object which i want to insert into the standard Object from Salesforce. The custom contact object is:

```
global class CContact 
{
    public String changed {get; set;}
    public String contactId {get; set;}
    public String customerNumber {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String firstName  {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String phoneCountryCode {get; set;}
    public String phoneNumber {get; set;}
    public String pointBalance {get; set;}
    public String contactUrl {get; set;}
}
```

What am i doing wrong below?
My upsert logic:

```
Contact[] cts;
string searchQuery = 'SELECT id, firstName FROM contact WHERE Membership_number__c = 123456789';
cts = Database.query(searchQuery);
System.debug('Cts length: ' + cts.size()); (Returns 1)
cts[0] = new Contact(phone = '555', email = ''); //Just hardcoding a new value here!
Schema.SObjectField f = Contact.Fields.Membership_number__c;
Database.UpsertResult [] cr = Database.upsert(cts, f, false);
cr[0].getId(); //This returns the ID of inserted/updated record ((Returns null now)
```

My upsert logic 2:

```
Contact cts;
string searchQuery = 'SELECT id, firstName FROM contact WHERE Membership_number__c = 123456789 LIMIT 1';
try
{
    cts = Database.query(searchQuery);
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
cts = new Contact(phone = '555', email = '', Membership_number__c = customerNumber);
Schema.SObjectField f = Contact.Fields.Membership_number__c;
Database.UpsertResult cr = Database.upsert(cts, f, false);
system.debug('is success: ' + cr.isSuccess()); //Returns false
system.debug('Id is: ' + cr.getId()); //This returns the ID of inserted/updated record
```

Comment: Have you tried checking errors from the upsert result? Also, have you considered using JSON serialization of the class to do this?

Comment: I haven't considered JSON Serialization, it's getting into the system as a XML object which I convert to a Salesforce Contact Object, and afterwards searches the Salesforce Database with the customernumber in the search query.
Can you elaborate how to check for errors on upsert result?

Comment: Look here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_upsertresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_upsertresult

Comment: Had to include the "Unique Key field" in the New Contact() initialization.
Thanks :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Database.UpsertResult cr = Database.upsert(cts[0], f, false);` since you're only inserting one record instead of an array.

Or recode to something like the following:

```
Contact cts;
string searchQuery = 'SELECT id, firstName FROM contact WHERE Membership_number__c = 123456789 limit 1';
cts = Database.query(searchQuery);
System.debug('Cts contains data: ' + cts.isEmpty()); (Returns False)
cts = new Contact(phone = '555', email = ''); //Just hardcoding a new value here!
Schema.SObjectField f = Contact.Fields.Membership_number__c;
Database.UpsertResult cr = Database.upsert(cts, f, false);  
cr.getId();
```

Also, following your query, you should already have the Id which is cts.Id

Comment: cts.size() is not valid for the above code

Comment: You're right, I was just copying and pasting without paying attention to his debug statements! Good catch! Will make an edit.

Comment: also one other thing, he still may see a null Id since there is no explicit database.upsertresult checker. I see that when the contact cts is being inserted the op is not providing an external Id ( membership_number__c) so the system would complain external Id not found. Unless there is an explicit check to see if database,upsertresult.issucess() the id would still return null

Comment: Understand, but then that wasn't part of his question, nor did he state he was using it as an external ID. I can't read minds. :)

Comment: :) I totally accept that we do not compile and provide a ready made answer, I was doing the compilation part since it has been long I looked into External Id topic. Sorry If I am picky :P, I already upvoted for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments, appreciate it.
When i run the code it gives me: "Expression must be a list type: Contact" error.
So, will it only work as a list, where I will refer the object as cts[0] every time then?
Have updated question with code example 2.

Comment: From the code you posted, the reason it has to be a list is because you didn't put `limit1` in your query string.

Comment: AHA. I actually thought of it. Now it works. 
But the ID from cr.getId() is still null.
Do you agree that below code is updating if search query returned a record (contact), and if it didn't return an object, it will insert a new contact in the DB? Or am i totally wrong here?

cts = new Contact(phone = '555', email = '');

Comment: Just updated the code example 2.

Comment: cts = new Contact(phone = '555', email = '', Membership_number__c = customerNumber);

Comment: Success at inserting a new contact would depend on any validation rules that might be in place. Have you been checking debug logs? If the query didn't return any results, following the insert, the Id of the record would be cts.Id of the newly inserted record. Add a debug statement to see what it is. A contact usually needs a name at a minimum and is typically associated with an account in most orgs.

Comment: I'm aware of firstName etc. requirements. And I actually just added try/catch logic for it to work, if query didnt return any record.

Answer (score -1):

Your search should be like this : 
string searchQuery = 'SELECT id, firstName,Membership_number__c  FROM contact WHERE Membership_number__c = 123456789';
and instead of "cts[0] = new Contact(phone = '555', email = '');"
use : 
cts[0].phone = '555';
cts[0].email = '';